# debian: not relying on DVDs when apt install

Tags: linux, debian, apt

Hello fellow superusers,

I installed a debian 10 with the first DVD out of the 3 DVDs set. My problem is, very often, when I install a new package with apt, from the Internet, debian asks for the DVD1. How can I configure debian so that it relies on Internet rather than DVDs? (I don't want to insert the DVDs each time).

Thank you very much,
/cr!ptal

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the CD from the sources.list found in the /etc/apt/ directory (note: you can use whatever editor you feel comfortable with).

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You can find more information [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList). Also, you might want to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To verify that it actually worked.

Comment: thank you, it works :-)